# Are there any tools/libraries that can convert tensorflow lstm model to .mlmodel format to run in iOS app

Tags: tensorflow, coreml, tensorflow-lite, swift-for-tensorflow

I have a simple tensorflow model that consists of lstm layers - such as *tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell* or *tf.keras.layers.LSTM* (I can provide the sample code also, if needed). I want to run the model on an iOS app. However, I have looked at several websites that say that presently there is **no way to convert and run tensorflow model that consist LSTM layers on iOS apps**.

I have tried these tools/libraries to convert the tensorflow model to .mlmodel format (or .tflite format)
1. Swift for Tensorflow
2. Tensorflow Lite for iOS
3. tfcoreml

However, these tools also does not seem to be able to convert the lstm layers model to .mlmodel format. These tools, however allow to use custom layers to be added. But I don't know how I can add LSTM custom layer.

Am I wrong in saying that there is no support to run tensorflow lstm model in iOS apps? If yes, then please guide me on how I can go ahead to include the model in iOS app. Is there any other tool/library that can be ued to convert it to .mlmodel format. If no, then are there any plans to include tensorflow support for iOS in future?

## Model

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import *

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)


#Summary parameters
logs_path = "logs/"

# Training Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_steps = 1000
batch_size = 128
display_step = 200

# Network Parameters
num_input = 28 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
timesteps = 28 # timesteps
num_hidden = 128 # hidden layer num of features
num_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, timesteps, num_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes])

# Define weights
weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden, num_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))
}


def RNN(x, weights, biases):
    # Unstack to get a list of 'timesteps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.unstack(x, timesteps, 1)

    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = rnn.LSTMBlockCell(num_hidden, forget_bias = 1.0)
    #lstm_cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(num_hidden, unit_forget_bias=True)

    # Get lstm cell output
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']

logits = RNN(X, weights, biases)
with tf.name_scope('Model'):
    prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name = "prediction_layer")

with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
    # Define loss and optimizer
    loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y, name = "loss_layer"), name = "reduce_mean_loss")

with tf.name_scope('SGD'):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, name = "Gradient_Descent")
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op, name = "minimize_layer")


with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
    # Evaluate model (with test logits, for dropout to be disabled)
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1), name = "correct_pred_layer")
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32), name = "reduce_mean_acc_layer")

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

#Create a summary to monitor cost tensor
tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss_op)
#Create a summary to monitor accuracy tensor
tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)
#Merge all summaries into a single op
merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = ""
model_save = "model.ckpt"

# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    # op to write logs to Tensorboard
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())

    for step in range(1, training_steps+1):
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)

        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        # Reshape data to get 28 seq of 28 elements
        batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size, timesteps, num_input))
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
        if step % display_step == 0 or step == 1:
            # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            loss, acc, summary = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                                 Y: batch_y})

            # Write logs at every iteration
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step * total_batch)

            print("Step " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.4f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.3f}".format(acc))
    saver.save(sess, model_save)
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, save_path, 'save_graph.pbtxt')
    #print(sess.graph.get_operations())

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    print("Run the command line:\n" \
            "--> tensorboard --logdir=logs/ " \
            "\nThen open http://0.0.0.0:6006/ into your web browser")

    # Calculate accuracy for 128 mnist test images
    test_len = 128
    test_data = mnist.test.images[:test_len].reshape((-1, timesteps, num_input))
    test_label = mnist.test.labels[:test_len]
    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
        sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: test_data, Y: test_label}))
```

Code to generate the frozen model

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph

save_path = ""
model_name = "test_model_tf_keras_layers_lstm"
input_graph_path = save_path + "save_graph.pbtxt"
checkpoint_path = save_path + "model.ckpt"
input_saver_def_path = ""
input_binary = False
output_node_names = "Model/prediction_layer" #output node's name. Should match to that mentioned in the code
restore_op_name = 'save/restore_all'
filename_tensor_name = 'save/const:0'
output_frozen_graph_name = save_path + 'frozen_model' + '.pb'   # name of .pb file that one would like to give
clear_devices = True

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path, input_saver_def_path, input_binary, checkpoint_path, output_node_names, restore_op_name, filename_tensor_name, output_frozen_graph_name, clear_devices, "")
print("Model Freezed")
```

## Conversion Code to generate .mlmodel format file

```
import tfcoreml

coreml_model = tfcoreml.convert(tf_model_path = 'frozen_model_test_model_tf_keras_layers_lstm.pb', 
                      mlmodel_path = 'test_model.mlmodel', 
                      output_feature_names = ['Model/prediction_layer:0'], 
                      add_custom_layers = True)


coreml_model.save("test_model.mlmodel")
```

Error message shown with
`lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_hidden, name = "lstm_cell")`

```
Value Error: Split op case not handled. Input shape = [1, 512], output shape = [1, 128]
```

Error message shown with
`lstm_cell = rnn.LSTMBlockCell(num_hidden, name = "lstm_cell")`

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'LSTMBlockCell' used by node rnn/lstm_cell/LSTMBlockCell (defined at /anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py:153) with these attrs: [forget_bias=1, use_peephole=false, cell_clip=-1, T=DT_FLOAT]
Registered devices: [CPU]
Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[node rnn/lstm_cell/LSTMBlockCell (defined at /anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py:153) ]]
```

I expect that the frozen tensorflow model can be converted to .mlmodel format.

Comment: I haven't tried converting a TF model with LSTMs to Core ML but I did convert a Keras model recently and that works fine (but not tf.keras). You do have to keep in mind that TF is much more flexible that Core ML when it comes to the shapes of tensors, etc. Also, the kinds of RNNs that Core ML supports is somewhat limited.

Comment: Hi @MatthijsHollemans, thanks for the response.
Did your Keras model contain LSTM layers? What type model did you use? Is IT a sequence-to-sequence model?

Comment: Yes, it contained a couple of LSTM layers (not bidirectional). It was a sequence classifier. So it is possible to make LSTM-based models with Core ML but perhaps converting from TF isn't always possible (at least not without writing your own converter).